# There exist infinitely many primes of the form $p = \lfloor\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n + 1}\rfloor$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it difficult to prove this existence problem?  There are infinitely many $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that :

$$
p = \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor
$$
is a prime number.

Attempt:

Every odd prime $p$ can be written $p = \lfloor{\dfrac{p}{2}} \rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac{p}{2} + 1\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{(\dfrac{p}{2})^2} \rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt{(\dfrac{p}{2} + 1)^2} \rfloor$

Comment: If we set $n=k^2-1$ , we get for every positive integer $k$ : $$\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1} \rfloor=2k-1$$ Obviously there are infinite many $k$ such that $2k-1$ is prime.

Comment: It is enough to prove $(k-1)^2=k^2-2k+1\le k^2-1$ which holds for $k\ge 1$. Then, $\sqrt{n}$ is at least $k-1$ , but obviously smaller than $k$. $k$ is added to this number giving a number at least $2k-1$ , but smaller than $2k$. Hence the floor of this number is $2k-1$.

Comment: How is this related to the twin prime conjecture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any odd prime $p=2k+1$, let $n=(k+1)^2-1$.

Comment: $\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}+k+1$. Now it follows from $k<\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}<k+1$.

Comment: $k^2<(k+1)^2-1<(k+1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $\sqrt{n} + \epsilon = \sqrt{n+1}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, squaring gives $n + 2\epsilon \sqrt{n} + \epsilon^{2} = n + 1$ therefore the equation $\epsilon^{2} + 2\epsilon \sqrt{n} - 1 = 0$ has solution $\epsilon = \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n - 1}$

For $n > 1$ this difference will always be less than 1, thus you arrive at the result that $\lfloor \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}\rfloor = 2k-1$  when $n+1 = k^2$